# Can I note "country of origin" about people?

Tags: phrase-usage

I'm writing a report and I have to write the personal data (such as full name, address, and the place where the person was born). Now I thought about writing "country of origin" but then I checked it on google and found [that article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_of_origin) which states:

> "Country of origin (COO), is the country of manufacture, production,
>   or growth where an article or product comes from."

From this article it seems that I can use it for everything except for people. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write *about* country of origin, but instead of writing 'country of origin', you would put 'nationality' or 'birth nationality'. In fact, isn't stating where they were born the same?

Comment: Thank you. Nationality doesn't do it necessarily since people can have 2 or more nationalities, but maybe birth nationality may be an alternative, I'm not sure.